# Google Places API: “This IP, site, or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key”

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am testing the Google Places API on the Flutter Android app.

When I send a request to the API I get a JSON result with the following error message:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.

To build the request, I went to the Google API console and generated my Android API Key based on my application package.

I'm using Google Maps on the app and trying to make a request to the Places API.

I put both Application restrictions and API restrictions in Google API console using package name and SHA1

Without restrictions Places API work but with restrictions it's not working.

Comment: Android SHA1 fingerprint restrictions on an API key only works with Maps SDK for Android, meaning it authenticates the map as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey). To authenticate, Places API you will need a separate API key that would be restricted with IP addresses.